# Gdal Polygonize, empty attribute table

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, gdal, polygonize

I am trying to polygonize one of my rasters with PyGIS. I do this with the below script.

```
sourceRaster = 
gdal.Open('RASTER.tiff')
sr_proj=sourceRaster.GetProjection()
raster_proj = osr.SpatialReference()
raster_proj.ImportFromWkt(sr_proj)

band = sourceRaster.GetRasterBand(1) 
print  band
bandArray = band.ReadAsArray()
outShapefile = "POLYGON"
driver = ogr.GetDriverByName("ESRI Shapefile")
outDatasource = driver.CreateDataSource(outShapefile+ ".shp")
outLayer = outDatasource.CreateLayer('polygonized', srs=raster_proj)
newField = ogr.FieldDefn(str(1), ogr.OFTInteger)
outLayer.CreateField(newField)

gdal.Polygonize( band, None, outLayer, -1, [], callback=None )
outDatasource.Destroy()
sourceRaster = None

print "finish"
```

When I run the above, a polygonized version of my raster file has been created. The polygon looks like expected, it at least seems to fit the raster.

[image: Raster and polygon projection]

The weird thing however is that the attribute table is empty and it looks like only the shadow is projected

also when I Print the band

```
    band = sourceRaster.GetRasterBand(1) 
print  band
```

Below is printed

```
osgeo.gdal.Band; proxy of Swig Object of type 'GDALRasterBandShadow *' at 0x12a90a450
finish
```

When I use the QGIS GDAL Polygonize inbuilt function, the polygon looks like expected with a populated Attribute table.

Who can help?

Answer (score 5):

Found out that the reason the attribute table was empty was due to

```
gdal.Polygonize( band, None, outLayer, -1, [], callback=None )
```

Updated it to

```
gdal.Polygonize( band, None, outLayer, 0, [], callback=None )
```

Now it also populates the actual values in the attribute table. Not sure what this parameter means, but it looks like it works now.

Does anyone know?

Comment: Documented in https://www.gdal.org/gdal__alg_8h.html#a3f522a9035d3512b5d414fb4752671b1. `iPixValField the attribute field index indicating the feature attribute into which the pixel value of the polygon should be written.` There is no attribute at index -1 as you defined in your first trial.